# relative path for ms-access db in app.config while creating .exe file

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i have project in c# and access 2010 i configure my db link in app.config file as seen below `<connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\projecty bashi nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\db_file.accdb" name="connectionString"/>
</connectionStrings>` an then in all my forms i use `string conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
db_con = new OleDbConnection(conString);` it works good ... but know i want to make .exe file for my project and i want to make db link work in any machine that i install the exe file?? can any one help me an explain it for me but in detail please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative path: db_file.accdb if database is placed in the same diractory as the exe file.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=db_file.accdb" name="connectionString"/> 
</connectionStrings>

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
db_con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
```

Comment: ok but can explain in detail how i can use relative path? but in detail please?

Comment: i put my db in my project folde, folder that conatian bin,obj,properties,rsources folder also all forms file ... know if i create .exe file for my project .. i works in any machines that i install on it?

Comment: your database should be in the same directory as the exe file. If you use VisualStudio for development you have to: 1) place the file to bin/Debug or bin/Release (depends on project configuration settings) or 2) place database in project folder (where bin and obj folder resides) add database file to project in VisualStudio and change the "Copy to output Directory" property to Copy Always.

Comment: Vasiliy i don't understand your answer well please explain it in another way that i understand? i use visual studio 2008 ... know when i create .exe file where i put my db file ... and when i install .exe file on another machine where i put the db file??